# What is a smart way to order (by ascending date) this array of object having a String field (representing a Date)?

Tags: java, java-8, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch project and I have the following problem (that it is not strictly related to Spring Batch).

I have this **NotaryDetailsEnrichProcessor** implementing the **ItemProcessor** interface, this one:

```
public class NotaryDetailsEnrichProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Notary, NotaryDetails> {
    
    @Autowired
    NotaryService notaryService;
    
    String notaryId = null;

    public NotaryDetailsEnrichProcessor(NotaryService notaryService) {
        super();
        this.notaryService = notaryService;
    }



    @Override
    public NotaryDetails process(Notary notary) throws Exception {
        this.notaryId = notary.getIdNotary();
        
        //System.out.println("NotaryDetailsEnrichProcessor process notaryId: " + notaryId);
        NotaryDetails notaryDetails = this.notaryService.getNotaryDetails(notaryId);
        
        //System.out.println("#####################################################");
        
        return notaryDetails;
    }

}
```

This processor basically retrieve the details of a specific object into a **NotaryDetails** instance.

This is the **NotaryDetails** class:

```
public class NotaryDetails {

    String idNotary;
    
    NotarySheet scheda;
    NotaryContact contatti;
    NotaryInformation informazioni;
    NotaryHistorical storico;
    
    public NotaryDetails() {
        super();
    }

    public NotaryDetails(String idNotary, NotarySheet scheda, NotaryContact contatti, NotaryInformation informazioni,
            NotaryHistorical storico) {
        super();
        this.idNotary = idNotary;
        this.scheda = scheda;
        this.contatti = contatti;
        this.informazioni = informazioni;
        this.storico = storico;
    }
    
    public String getIdNotary() {
        return idNotary;
    }

    public void setIdNotary(String idNotary) {
        this.idNotary = idNotary;
    }

    public NotarySheet getScheda() {
        return scheda;
    }

    public void setScheda(NotarySheet scheda) {
        this.scheda = scheda;
    }

    public NotaryContact getContatti() {
        return contatti;
    }

    public void setContatti(NotaryContact contatti) {
        this.contatti = contatti;
    }

    public NotaryInformation getInformazioni() {
        return informazioni;
    }

    public void setInformazioni(NotaryInformation informazioni) {
        this.informazioni = informazioni;
    }

    public NotaryHistorical getStorico() {
        return storico;
    }

    public void setStorico(NotaryHistorical storico) {
        this.storico = storico;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NotaryDetails [idNotary=" + idNotary + ", scheda=" + scheda + ", contatti=" + contatti
                + ", informazioni=" + informazioni + ", storico=" + storico + "]";
    }
    
}
```

As you can see it contains this field:

```
NotaryHistorical storico;
```

Where **NotaryHistorical** is this class:

```
public class NotaryHistorical {
    
    NotaryOffice[] sedi;

    public NotaryHistorical() {
        super();
    }

    public NotaryHistorical(NotaryOffice[] sedi) {
        super();
        this.sedi = sedi;
    }

    public NotaryOffice[] getSedi() {
        return sedi;
    }

    public void setSedi(NotaryOffice[] sedi) {
        this.sedi = sedi;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NotaryHistorical [sedi=" + Arrays.toString(sedi) + "]";
    }
    

}
```

that itself contains this array field:

```
NotaryOffice[] sedi;
```

where **NotaryOffice** is:

```
public class NotaryOffice {
    
    String sede;
    String dal;
    String note;
    String stato;
    
    public NotaryOffice() {
        super();
    }

    public NotaryOffice(String sede, String dal, String note, String stato) {
        super();
        this.sede = sede;
        this.dal = dal;
        this.note = note;
        this.stato = stato;
    }

    public String getSede() {
        return sede;
    }

    public void setSede(String sede) {
        this.sede = sede;
    }

    public String getDal() {
        return dal;
    }

    public void setDal(String dal) {
        this.dal = dal;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public String getStato() {
        return stato;
    }

    public void setStato(String stato) {
        this.stato = stato;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NotaryOffice [sede=" + sede + ", dal=" + dal + ", note=" + note + ", stato=" + stato + "]";
    }

}
```

Ok we finally have this String field:

```
String dal;
```

this field represents a **Date** as a String in the format **DD/MM/AAAA** (it is a String and not a Date because it is used to write on a WordPress post accepting only String).

Ok now my problem is that into my **process()** method of my **NotaryDetailsEnrichProcessor**, after that I retrieve the **NotaryDetails** (calling the service, here:

```
NotaryDetails notaryDetails = this.notaryService.getNotaryDetails(notaryId);
```

I need to order by ascending date the array, based on the value of this field: **NotaryDetails --> NotaryHistorical --> NotaryOffice --> dal**

So I suppose that basically **dal** (that is a String) have to be converted on a **Date** and that the related value can be used to order the **NotaryOffice[]** array.

What could be an elegant solution for this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a Comparator that uses the dal date string values for the comparison.  For example...

```
public class NotaryHistorical {
    
    NotaryOffice[] sedi;

    public NotaryHistorical() {}

    public NotaryHistorical(NotaryOffice[] sedi) {
        setSedi(sedi);
    }

    public NotaryOffice[] getSedi() {
        return sedi;
    }

    public void setSedi(NotaryOffice[] sedi) {
        this.sedi = Arrays.stream(sedi)
            .sorted((a,b) -> { 
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
                return LocalDate.parse(a.getDal(), formatter).compareTo(LocalDate.parse(b.getDal(), formatter));
            })
            .toArray(NotaryOffice[]::new);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NotaryHistorical [sedi=" + Arrays.toString(sedi) + "]";
    }
    

}
```